# Problems with commands to configure the NAT on CISCO ubr7200 series

Tags: command-line-interface, command, modem, nat, cisco

I have a Cisco uBR7200 series CMTS with these features:

---

Cisco Internetwork Operating System Software
IOS (tm) 7200 Software (uBR7200-K8P-M), Version 12.3 (9a) BC9, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

Cisco uBR7246VXR (NPE400) processor (revision A) with 458752K/65536K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID SPE121401EK
R7000 CPU at 350MHz, Implementation 39, Rev 3.3, 256KB L2, 4096KB L3 Cache
6 slot VXR midplane, Version 2.0

Last reset from power-on
X.25 software, Version 3.0.0.

PCI bus bandwidth mb0_mb1 has 442 points
PCI bus mb2 has 0 bandwidth points

2 FastEthernet / IEEE 802.3 interface (s)
1 Cable Modem network interface (s)
125K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.

47040K bytes of ATA PCMCIA card at slot 0 (Sector size 512 bytes).
8192K bytes of Flash internal SIMM (Sector size 256K).

---

And the problem is that I can't use any command related to NAT (Network Address Translation) and therefore I can't configure that table, I'm talking about commands like these: ip nat, ip nat inside destination, ip nat inside source, ip nat outside source, ip nat pool, ip nat translation, show ip nat statistics, show ip nat translations....

It seems that my Cisco CMTS uBR7200 doesn't have NAT, but the commands exist.... Could anyone tell me what's happening? Why doesn't it have a NAT table or why am I not able to put any command related with NAT in the CISCO IOS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably find the IOS with "Plus" feature like "ubr7200-is-mz", and moving this to serverfault

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Cisco's Feature navigator](http://cisco.com/go/fn) and look for "NAT-PT" for example. A drop-down menu will appear and let you choose what you want :

- **ios** vs ios-XR
- IOS major release (12.3BC9 here)
- Release (9a)
- platform : 7200

It will show what IOSes contain this feature. Yours is not listed, because it doesn't allow NAT.

And by the way, you should really upgrade to a newer version (12.4 sth) as your hardware supports newer IOSes (48MB flash, 512MB ram).

Answer (score 0):

The Cisco UBR7246VXR most definitely do NAT. But as was already said in the comment you would need an IOS with i or s keyword in it. That is you should change yor IOS from ubr7200-k8p-m to ubr7200-i8s-m which is a similar image but with NAT supported included.

See table3 here (or search for one of the IOS images).
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/cable/cmts/ubr7200/release/notes/12_3bc/123BCu72.html